# Unable to acces variable in aspx page

Tags: asp.net

Iam tried to access a variable from aspx page.But i got an error "inaccesible due to its protection level".Iam using an listview and inside item template iam tried to access id by using a variable.

My codes

```
 <ItemTemplate>
            value1 = '<%#Eval("TheatreDetailsId") %>';
             <% object value = value1;%>//here value1 is inaccessible
             <%List<object> lst = new List<object>();
             lst.Add(value);%>
        <td><asp:HiddenField ID="hidfield" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("TheatreDetailsId") %>'></asp:HiddenField>
 </ItemTemplate>
```

For accessible the variable what should i do?

Comment: How is `value1` defined in your code behind?

Comment: Your code having errors. Show us the declaration for value1.

Comment: Why you are creating `List<object>` in your markup code? Its dangerous as well as non maintainable at all. You are clearly violating the separation of concerns principle which _Webforms_ anyhow don't conform with.

Answer (score 0):

Add scope to your variable like this.

```
public string variable;
```

It will be accessible on aspx page like that :

```
<%=variable%>
```